# how to perform operations in queries programatically?

Tags: java, postgresql

How to do the operation `w_balance = w_balance + amount` in the query String? One way is to perform the operation outside the Query String. But is there a way to do that directly? Here, `amount` is the new amount I would want to add or subtract from the `w_balance`.

My database is postgresql.

```
String SQL = "update walletapp.users_acc set w_balance = w_balance + amount where kyc_id = :sender_id";
```

I used - `String SQL = "update walletapp.users_acc set w_balance = w_balance + :amount where kyc_id = :sender_id";`   which solved my problem.

Comment: Did you tried to do the assign of the variable ? Because you can.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter the same way you pass the sender_id parameter: `set w_balance = w_balance + :amount`

Comment: I would update your question to only ask about the assignation of `w_balance` outside of the postgresql context if this is what you asked. From what I understand, you are just trying to assign a variable while creating a String. The SQL is just messing with the possible answers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  it works properly. Pleaseput it as an answer to the question.

Comment: @AxelH Well, I only wanted to do  wbalance= wbalance + amount inside the query. That's all. w_balance and amount are not string. I am adding amount to w_balance, every time the query is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by @a_horse_with_no_name  `set w_balance = w_balance + :amount`  worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of an assignation of a value an the usage of it :

```
int i = 0;
System.out.println(i = 5);
String s = "The Value is " + (i = 4);
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(i);
```

This will output

> 5
>
> The Value is 4
>
> 4

So you see that you can set the variable an recover it at the same time, this is just some operator priority

Answer (score -2):

Assing it to a variable or do it directly. A good way to do it is using String.format:

```
String SQL = String.format("update walletapp.users_acc set w_balance = %d where kyc_id = :sender_id", w_balance + amount);
```

Comment: Just dont do string replacements. You open doors to sql injection. Use a variable.

Comment: It Just happen if you're a careless person and put response params values in it.  Otherwise it's never gonna happening.

Comment: Not only is using string replacements bad for security, it is also bad for performance, because it prevents benefiting from prepared statements.

Comment: @Brian, for performance I agree (if there is multiple update at the same time) but for security, here I would not point this out since this is (or should be) primitives types, so hard to do any injection with them (or am I wrong ?)

Comment: In this case, regarding the primitive type, I agree. It should be fairly hard to inject any SQL, if possible at all. But I personally wouldn't even bother thinking about it, because of standards (prepared or callable statements in this case).